# Mule facebook connector, failing to publish a post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, mule

I am trying to use facebook connector in mule, I've 2 flows, one to authorize, and the other to post a simple text in facebook. The problem is after authorizing my program, I lose the accessTokenID, and it can't be saved.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:facebook="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/facebook" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/facebook http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/facebook/2.0/mule-facebook.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd">
    <facebook:config-with-oauth name="Facebook" appId="appID" appSecret="appSecret" doc:name="Facebook" scope="publish_stream">
        <facebook:oauth-callback-config domain="${fullDomain}" localPort="${http.port}"/>
    </facebook:config-with-oauth>
    <flow name="Authorization" doc:name="Authorization">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="${http.port}" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <facebook:authorize config-ref="Facebook" doc:name="Facebook"/>
        <set-session-variable doc:name="Save Access Token" value="\#[flowVars['OAuthAccessTokenId']]" variableName="accessTokenId"/>
        <flow-ref name="posting" doc:name="post on facebook"/>
    </flow>
    <flow name="posting" doc:name="posting">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="${http.port}" path="post" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <facebook:publish-message config-ref="Facebook" msg="Hi, I am from Mule, where are you from?" profile_id="myprofileID" doc:name="Facebook" accessTokenId="\#[sessionVars['accessTokenId']]"/>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

And this is the error I get in cloudhub:

```
********************************************************************************
Message               : null
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. null (org.mule.api.store.ObjectStoreNotAvaliableException)
  com.mulesoft.ch.objectstore.proxy.ObjectStoreProxyImpl:59 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/store/ObjectStoreNotAvaliableException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.store.ObjectStoreNotAvaliableException
    at com.mulesoft.ch.objectstore.proxy.ObjectStoreProxyImpl.contains(ObjectStoreProxyImpl.java:59)
    at com.mulesoft.ch.objectstore.ObjectStoreImpl.contains(ObjectStoreImpl.java:31)
    at org.mule.module.facebook.oauth.FacebookConnectorOAuthClientFactory.makeObject(FacebookConnectorOAuthClientFactory.java:31)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Anyone can help me with it? I think that session-variable won't be saved, but there's no way I can prove it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you have a slash before your accessTokenId expression? Here: \#[flowVars['OAuthAccessTokenId']] and here: \#[sessionVars['accessTokenId']]. Try removing those, also try logging the value <logger level="INFO" message="My token === #[flowVars['OAuthAccessTokenId']]" and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, you saved me a lot of pain!

Comment: Can you add it as the answer, so I can choose yours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a leading slash here: #[flowVars['OAuthAccessTokenId']] and here: #[sessionVars['accessTokenId']]. Try removing those, also try logging the value

Answer (score 0):

For future references, as of now : 
the Code on https://github.com/mulesoft/facebook-connector/blob/master/doc/sample.md is wrong, in flow it used the same '\' that I have in my code :

```
<flow name="Authorize" doc:name="Authorize">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <facebook:authorize config-ref="Facebook-config" doc:name="Authorize"/>
    <set-session-variable doc:name="Save Access Token" value="\#[flowVars['OAuthAccessTokenId']]" variableName="accessTokenId"/>
    <flow-ref name="PhotoDownload" doc:name="Call Photo Download"/>
</flow>
```

Hopefully they'll correct it in the future